# Malloc chunk content

Tags: c, malloc, chunks

I want to found the chunk struct used by malloc

the [source code](http://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html) says that it looks like this:

```
struct malloc_chunk {

  INTERNAL_SIZE_T      prev_size;  /* Size of previous chunk (if free).  */
  INTERNAL_SIZE_T      size;       /* Size in bytes, including overhead. */

  struct malloc_chunk* fd;         /* double links -- used only if free. */
  struct malloc_chunk* bk;

  /* Only used for large blocks: pointer to next larger size.  */
  struct malloc_chunk* fd_nextsize; /* double links -- used only if free. */
  struct malloc_chunk* bk_nextsize;
}
```

But this code do invalid reads:

```
int main()
{
  struct malloc_chunk *chunk;
  void                *ptr;

  ptr = malloc(10);
  chunk = ptr - sizeof(struct malloc_chunk);
  printf("%p\n", chunk->fd);
}
```

I then tried to found the chunk size with this:

```
int main()
{
   void  *ptr1;
   void  *ptr2;

   ptr1 = malloc(10);
   ptr2 = malloc(10);

   printf("%d\n", ptr2 - ptr1 - 10);
}
```

And I get for size:

> - 10  : 22
> - 500 : 12
> - 31  : 31

How could I get the meta data of malloc ?

Comment: What about the code that actually returns the user pointer?  Are you sure it places it immediately after the chunk?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but arithmetic with void pointers (such as `ptr - sizeof(struct malloc_chunk)`) is - as far as I know - a non-standard GCC feature.

Comment: Also, is there a specific reason you want to get hold of the chunk data?  (Or is it just curiosity?)

Comment: I want to recode malloc :)

Comment: Did you compile that particular implementation yourself? If not yours might be different. Also malloc uses different parts of the struct for different types( sized ) of chunks. Some members are ignored and overwritten( not used ).

Comment: @nsvir did you fix your code?

Comment: I don't remember being able to read the meta data behind the malloc used by my kernel. But I was still able to create my own malloc system call :)

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the comment right after the `malloc_chunk` declaration, you'll see the following:

```
/*
malloc_chunk details:

(The following includes lightly edited explanations by Colin Plumb.)

Chunks of memory are maintained using a `boundary tag' method as
described in e.g., Knuth or Standish. (See the paper by Paul
Wilson ftp://ftp.cs.utexas.edu/pub/garbage/allocsrv.ps for a
survey of such techniques.) Sizes of free chunks are stored both
in the front of each chunk and at the end. This makes
consolidating fragmented chunks into bigger chunks very fast. The
size fields also hold bits representing whether chunks are free or
in use.

An allocated chunk looks like this:


    chunk-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
            | Size of previous chunk, if allocated                        | |
            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
            | Size of chunk, in bytes                                   |M|P|
      mem-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
            | User data starts here...                                      .
            .                                                               .
            . (malloc_usable_size() bytes)                                  .
            .                                                               |
nextchunk-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
            |  Size of chunk                                                |
            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

            ...

*/
```

Note where it says `"User data starts here..."` - when dealing with an allocated block of memory, the pointer to the user memory block starts *inside* the `malloc_chunk` structure.

Implementations of memory allocators (particularly production implementations) often use hacks that would be considered very bad coding practice in most code.  They do this because the memory allocation routines are very heavily used, and small gains in time and space often add up to large differences in program performance.